# Multiple refresh-able select lists in a single page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have 6 select lists on a page, and data is being pulled in each select list using a SQL Query. Is there any way that selecting data in any select list will refresh data in all other select lists, irrespective of the order in which data is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those select lists depend on each other - and yes, they do, as changing one of them reflects others - then use

- cascading LOV parent item(s) and/or
- items to submit

properties to do that.

---

If items depend on each other, but not in strict parent-child relationship, then

- in their queries use `WHERE` clauses which will make result of each query dependent on other items' values, e.g.

  ```
  where (continent = :P1_CONTINENT or :P1_CONTINENT is null)
    and (country = :P1_COUNTRY or :P1_COUNTRY is null)
  ```
- set their *page action on selection* property to "Redirect and set value" so that other items' values are refreshed once you modify this item's value
- do **not** set *cascading list of values parent item* as you'll create circular reference and the page won't work

Comment: I have tried that. Issue with that is how do I refresh data in Parent Select List, when data in child list is selected? Any help would be of great help.

Comment: I added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: That works. But now, upon changing a value in any list prompts a popup saying: "Leave Site? Changes you have made may not be saved." How to remove this pop up?

Comment: That's easy; navigate to page's property palette and turn off **warn on unsaved changes**.